# JDOM: creating element from string, which contain xml-code

Tags: xml, escaping, jdom

I'm parsing some text input to xml using jdom. It have structure like:

```
<item>
  <text>Some description</text>
  <options .... />
</item>
<item>
  <text>Some description 2</text>
  <options .... />
</item>
```

Then, I need a regular w3c.dom object. I'm using this code:

```
    DOMOutputter domOutputter = new DOMOutputter();
    org.w3c.dom.Document w3cDoc = domOutputter.output( doc );
```

I'm creating element with this code:

```
Element desc = new Element("tekst");
String description = //some function returning string
desc.addContent(description);
e.setContent(desc);
```

Where e is new Element("item")

It works fine, but problem is when in "description" user inserts some xml tags. I'd like to handle it. I have output like:

```
<text>&lt;bold&gt;description&lt;/bold&gt;</text>
```

Is there any way to automaticaly parse those  tags when creating Element? 
From the w3cDoc I'm creating Source with DOMSource and it's needed for further transformation. Maybe there should I replace escaped brackets?

__

dce

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/output/XMLOutputter.html

specifically at

http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/output/XMLOutputter.html#escapeAttributeEntities(java.lang.String)

http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/output/XMLOutputter.html#escapeElementEntities(java.lang.String)

Comment: I want to do the oposite thing to "escape". I want to get output of last example to be: <text><bold>....</bold></text>.